# Get information from virtual machine manager using php

Tags: 11.04, virtualization, php, virtualhost

[image]

Is it possible to retrieve information from virtual machine manager using a php code? i tried through exec commands but couldn't get anything in browser as result. Please any help to complete this task.

Am using Ubuntu server 11.04 and kvm as hyper-visor. I have installed virtual machine manager.

Please don't suggest any tool to install.

Comment: What is the code you are trying to use>

Comment: function vmstatus() 
   {
    exec("/usr/bin/virsh list --all  | tr -s ' '| cut -f3 -d' ' | sed '1,2d'  ",$test);
    exec("/usr/bin/virsh list --all  | tr -s ' '| cut -f4 -d' ' | sed '1,2d'  ",$testa);
    foreach($testa as $status) 
    {
     foreach($test as $virshlist) 
     {
      echo "<tr><td>".$virshlist."</td><td>".$status."</td></tr>\n";

     }
    }
   }

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php:

You'll need to use an array to get output.

So, use the following code:

```
$result=[]; // Create an array
exec('your command line', &$result);  // Remember the & before the result as it ***IS A REFERENCE***
//DO whatever with your result
```

The problem is that you didn't pass your result array as a reference.

Or, use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), where your return value is everything returned:

```php
$return=shell_exec($command_line);
```

You can also use backticks:

```php
$result=`cmdline`
```

## Or, use `popen(`:

Create a new pointer with:

```php
$handle = popen("/bin/ls", "r");
```

and then read it:

```php
$read = fread($handle);
```

and close with:

```
pclose($handle);
```

It will block execution until the output stops.

Comment: Thanks for info but i already tried those things.echo "VM List: ";
   $vm = shell_exec('virsh list');
   echo "<pre>$vm</pre>"; but am not getting any output.

Comment: Is it need any connect code as like connecting with sql for virsh to be connected with php code?

Comment: @PoorniMa No, but you can try to use `popen(` as I will show in my answer.

Comment: can you give complete code

Comment: @PoorniMa See edits below `popen(` heading in my answer.

Comment: @PoorniMa If it helps you, please accept this answer with the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: not working :-(

Comment: @PoorniMa Why? What is the output when run directly?

Answer (score 0):

PHP functions like `exec()` or `shell_exec()` won't help because libvirt executes in root mode, while PHP executes as `www-data` user. We can give `www-data` root privileges, but there may be some security issues in that case. So best way is to use libvirt-php API. For example, to list all the VM in php:

```
<?php
     $conn = libvirt_connect('null', false);
     $doms = libvirt_list_domains($conn);
     print_r($doms);
?>
```

References:

- http://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html
- http://libvirt.org/php/examples.html

This will execute smoothly if libvirt is listening on a TCP port. To make libvirt listening on a tcp port, this question will help: [I can't use libvirt with listen TCP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423425/i-cant-use-libvirt-with-listen-tcp)