# I can't use libvirt with listen TCP

Tags: virtualization

I can't figure out how to enable libvirt with '-l' option (--listen) tcp conections in Ubuntu. I think that this is a bug.

I tried the following, without success:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/557054

But libvirtd only runs with -d option. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. What I'm doing wrong? Someone could help me?

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Libvirt_daemon_is_not_listening_on_tcp_ports_although_configured_to

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution, actually you also need to supply -l option to libvirt-bin init script.

**Enable TCP in the libvirt service on the host OS.**

```
Edit /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf to set:
listen_tls = 0
listen_tcp = 1
auth_tcp="none"
tcp_port = "16509"
```

**Configure the libvirt service to listen on TCP**

```
Edit /etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf to add the "-l" argument:
exec /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d -l
```

**Restart libvirt service**

```
Invoke: service libvirt-bin restart
```

**Test libvirt is started with “-l” parameter **

```
Invoke: ps -ef | grep libvirt
```

**Verify that the output contains the "-l" argument:**

```
.... /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d -l
```

The source: http://pineapplesoftware.blogspot.com.tr/2012/11/configuring-unsecure-remote-access-to.html

Comment: In case someone can't find where to put the `-l` flag, I have found it in the file `/etc/default/libvirtd` the line is `libvirtd_opts="-l"`. Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 2):

Since there are small inconsistencies in @Mustafa answer, I am rewriting some of the 'steps'. The following was tested on Ubuntu 12.04

1. Update the libvirt configurations. Modify /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf

   > before : #listen_tls = 0
   >   after : listen_tls = 0
   >
   > before : #listen_tcp = 1
   >   after : listen_tcp = 1
   >
   > add: auth_tcp = "none"
2. Modify /etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf. (-l is short for –listen)

   > before : env libvirtd_opts="-d"
   >   after : env libvirtd_opts="-d -l"
3. Modify /etc/default/libvirt-bin.

   > before :libvirtd_opts=" -d"
   >   after :libvirtd_opts=" -d -l"
4. Restart libvirt. After executing the command, ensure that libvirt is successfully restarted.

   > # stop libvirt-bin && start libvirt-bin
   >   $ ps -ef | grep libvirt

The output of the last one should be something like:

```
root     XXXXX     1 22 07:55 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d -l
```

Comment: I don't think that you need to edit `/etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf`. I got away with just editing `/etc/default/libvirt-bin`

Comment: @jkurtisr32 I have encounter 1-2 cases where, only one of the two was working, so I am configuring both of them, in order to be sure.

Comment: In my case (ubuntu 16.10) the "-l" option was ignored in any of the above files and it worked only when I added it in `/etc/default/libvirtd`

Comment: I did all the steps but I still got this error                                   
                                         nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: ab64119d-d075-4c99-8687-788695711b32] Migration operation has aborted

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `/etc/pki/CA/` certificates
or configure `libvirtd` with `listen_tls = 0` option

Comment: +1 this actually helped me. If you don't uncomment the `listen_tls` option, it will not be disabled

Answer (score 0):

Solve problem for Ubuntu 15.10

`$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/libvirt-bin.service`

Change line
`ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $LIBVIRTD_ARGS`
to
`ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd -l $LIBVIRTD_ARGS`
add -l option

Then:
`$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`$ sudo service libvirt-bin restart`